# How does Google Maps decide when to use a specific icon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using the Google Maps Places library to do a search for nearby hospitals, but it returns results that aren't necessary hospitals (but have 'hospital' as one of their types). However, I've noticed that actual hospitals have a hospital icon on the map, so Google must somehow know which establishments are *actually* hospitals. Does anyone know if the public has access to this data?

This is the icon I'm referring to: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jfqcayxavjhlyi/Screenshot%202015-03-17%2017.20.19.png?dl=0

Example of request I'm making:

```
 var request = {
    location: self.location,
    radius: 20000,
    types: ['hospital'],
    keyword: 'hospital'
  };
```

Example result that isn't a hospital:

```
{"geometry":{"location":{"k":44.815958,"D":-68.808244}},
"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","id":"de6e60bd70b90ba4cb86afe149a60169553607f1",
"name":"Penobscot Community Health Center",
"opening_hours":{"open_now":true,"weekday_text":[]},
"photos":[{"height":320,"html_attributions":[],"width":320}],"place_id":"ChIJj--4INRKrkwRN0z2XkoJtVU",
"rating":3.1,
"reference":"CoQBdAAAADmf3YA0659efzMbCSPOK6SZttkfus7aWBDhrZZyX63Szl256BRcpz81LH6rIuONldYv256tsN7Zv-N6ZkOkJadlD2VS01bs7C4ierKvGUMyJOJu657xL5MvidF3Tgs9iejeJcXsxjDJYOwtN3m3sbfClfWYVnnIL4hMLYV8P9TnEhBurfJv_30CAG2wp1V73POVGhR-7fz1mCdh4OYWSa3Pw0mPupckoQ",
"scope":"GOOGLE",
"types":["hospital","pharmacy","store","health","establishment"],
"vicinity":"1012 Union Street, Bangor",
"html_attributions":[]}
```

Comment: Could it be that `keyword: 'hospital'` is giving you results that have the keyword of hospital but aren't actually of type hospital?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there are a couple ways to get around this. You might remove the `keyword` argument from the API, which acts like a search term rather than a specific match on a type of location like the `type` field does.

You may want to be careful about your `radius` value choice.

Next, if you do a search on Google Maps in general you'll get a broad assortment of results. Do you need *every* result to be an actual hospital or can you do your own filtering afterwards?

If you do your own filtering it looks like type information and even icons are embedded in the result JSON. You might see if there's a distinguishing characteristic between the types of results you want and filter by that. Otherwise, any additional graphical data would not be accessible via the API.

Comment: Ya, the problem seems to be that there is nothing unique to *just* hospitals in the results. Other than filtering by keywords in the names (which could miss hospitals with unique names), I'm not sure how else to tackle it. Even the icons embedded in the results are not specific to hospitals.